# Why do some sites have a md5 string on each file?

Tags: hash, download, checksum

On some sites, in their download section each file has a md5. md5 of what? i cant understand the purpose

on phpBB.com for example:

```
Download phpBB 3.0.6 (zip)
Size: 2.30 MiB
MD5: 63e2bde5bd03d8ed504fe181a70ec97a
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the signature of the file's hash.  The idea is that you can run MD5 against the downloaded file, then compare it against that value to make sure you did not end up with a corrupted download.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum), for verifying that the file as-downloaded is intact, without transmission errors. If the checksum listing is on a different server than the download, it also may give a little peace of mind that the download server hasn't been hacked (with the presumption that two servers are harder to hack than one).

Answer (score 2):

It's a hash of the file. Used to ensure file integrity once you download said file. You'd use an md5 checksum tool to verify the file state.

Answer (score 2):

Sites will post checksums so that you can make sure the file downloaded is the same as the file they're offering. This lets you ensure that file has not been corrupted or tampered with.

On most unix operating systems you can run md5 or md5sum on a file to get the hash for it. If the hash you get matches the hash from the website, you can be reasonably certain that the file is intact. A quick Google search will get you md5sum utilities for Windows.

You might also see an SHA-1 hash sometimes. It's the same concept, but a different and more secure algorithm.

Comment: I agree with the intent and think that's why people do it, especially in a mirroring environment. However, one thing to think about is that if an attacker can tamper with the file, he might also update the hash to be a hash of the tampered file. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an md5 hash of the entire binary contents of the file. The point is that if two files have different md5 hashes, they are different. This helps you determine whether a local file on your computer is the same as the file on the website, without having to download it again. For instance:

- You downloaded your local copy somewhere else and think there might be a virus inside.
- Your connection is lossy and you fear the file might be corrupted by the download.
- You have changed the local file name and want to know which version you have.